# Malformed hostname in an MX record, possible?

Tags: dns, email, smtp

I'm wondering if it's possible to publish (and receive) a malformed hostname (e.g. a hostname starting with a digit or with a hyphen, etc.) in MX lookups? Does the DNS server usually validate MX records before accepting them?

For example,

- `0mx.example.com`
- `-host.domain.com`
- `host. domain.com`

Even if it's not allowed, let's assume that a malformed hostname was published somehow. Can I assume that a "good" DNS server (e.g., Google DNS) will not forward such a malformed hostname in MX lookup?

I'm implementing something relevant and need to know if I can "trust" MX lookups to return well-formatted hostnames all the time.

Comment: Can you define your understanding of "malformed hostname"?

Comment: Hey @RomeoNinov, I meant hostname with invalid syntax

Comment: Still not clear, please add example. In the question.

Comment: Sure @RomeoNinov! I just edited the description, take a look

Comment: I still do not see example. One possible malformed hostname can be test_host.example.com What is your example?

Comment: Here's a couple examples: "0mx.example.com", "-host.domain.com", "host.<space>domain.com"

Comment: If you're not 100% sure you created data yourself, validate it before using it. Always. In any context. Even if DNS servers generally validated MX records, nothing stops me from creating a malicious server that responds with whatever I want. This allows me to hack your software if you don't validate the MX record first. So, don't omit validation. Never. Ever.

Answer (score 4):

DNS allows for "any binary string" to appear, per [RFC 2181] "11.
Name syntax":

> The DNS itself places only one restriction on the particular labels
> that can be used to identify resource records.  That one restriction
> relates to the length of the label and the full name.  The length of
> any one label is limited to between 1 and 63 octets.  A full domain
> name is limited to 255 octets (including the separators).  The zero
> length full name is defined as representing the root of the DNS tree,
> and is typically written and displayed as ".".  Those restrictions
> aside, any binary string whatever can be used as the label of any
> resource record.  Similarly, any binary string can serve as the value
> of any record that includes a domain name as some or all of its value
> (SOA, NS, MX, PTR, CNAME, and any others that may be added).

so exactly how your DNS servers, clients, and mail transport software
handle such data would need to be tested.

Comment: RFC2181 states that it is clarifying ambiguities in earlier RFC's, not overriding the rules. RFC [1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) is clear that a hostname starts with a letter, ends with a letter or digit, and consists only of letters, digits, and hypens.

Comment: Given that bitsquatting is a thing it might be prudent to test how your DNS software handles unexpected octets showing up. Also if an attacker can do something with a DNS packet...

Comment: @doneal24: 1123 section 2.1 allows hostname to start with digit, although it states this as an update to 952 not to 1035 as it probably should

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you creating a non-validating DNS server. I don't think anyone here will be able to give a definitive answer about the way in which Google's DNS server would handle such records without trying it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Will DNS server software check the syntax of the MX hostname for illegal characters?  Some will some won't.

Will software acting as a cacheing DNS resolver perform a validity check on hostnames it receives from an authoritative DNS server?  I doubt it.

Will any DNS software check that a host named as the target in an MX record is listening on a valid SMTP port?  No, I've never encountered any such validation in DNS servers, though it's conceivable someone could write one.

Are you worried that a DNS record you create in your domain zone(s) could have an error?  I would suggest you create such records with a short TTL (time-to-live) and then test them.  After you've verified the new DNS record is good, you can change its TTL to the normal length of time.  (the short TTL means a broken record won't stay cached long before it's replaced by your fix)